# How to display the remoted iOS simulator log?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

i'm using this command

```
tail -f -1000 ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/EE257D24-E3E5-4F9E-B123-97A2587825E5/system.log
```

since a long time to display ios simulator logs on Mac.

Using Xamarin in Visual Studio for Windows with remoted iOS simulator activated, how to display this log without starting a debugging session ?

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 10, syslog is not the primary logging daemon.  Some logs end up there, but most end up in the new logging system.  You should run:

```
xcrun simctl spawn EE257D24-E3E5-4F9E-B123-97A2587825E5 log stream
```

Comment: I missed that. Thanks ! Found info there: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/721wh2etddp4ghxhpcg/721/721_unified_logging_and_activity_tracing.pdf

Comment: When the simulator is already launched, is there a way to change its logging type and target ? And how to read the same logs from a device connected to the mac ? I was using the open source deviceconsole app.

Comment: What do you mean by "logging type" and "target"?  Are you looking for `simctl spawn booted log config --help`?  The easiest way to read the logs is by opening up Console.